# onChange Event not trigerred

Tags: html, textbox, onchange

AM sure there is something that am missing in this html. The onChange event never gets fired. anyone help?? Thanks

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C/DTD XHTML 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml11/DTD/xhtml11.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en">
  <head>
    <title>Wake up call</title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      function v(elementName) {    // Function is defined here
        alert(elementName);
      }
    </script>
  </head>

  <body bgcolor="lightblue">
    <form>
      <input type="text"
        value="Wake me" id="wake"
        onchange="v(wake)">
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I quickly copied your code in a jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/asgoth/WM37M/

It seems to work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you don't have a variable named `wake`. either change it to a string:

```
 <input type="text" value="Wake me" id="wake" onchange="v('wake')">
```

or if it's meant to be a variable, set the variable somewhere.